# Why I get an "a.exe" instead of "a.out" on window C programming

Tags: c, compilation

When I compile below "hello_world.c" through cc hello_world.c, 
it makes an 'a.exe' instead of 'a.out'

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("hello, world\n");
}
```

1. What is a difference between "a.out" and "a.exe" ?
2. Why I get an "a.exe" instead of "a.out" ?

Comment: That depends of your compiler and it's settings. State the compiler and it's settings

Comment: Because executable files have a .exe extension on Windows, but not on other platforms.

Comment: I'm sorry but, how can i check the version of my compiler? I installed the visual studio 2015 on windows 10 and i compiled the code as "cc hello_world.c"

Comment: Read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.exe

Answer (score 9):

That depends on your platform. For example `gcc` will produce `.out` on linux, and `.exe` on windows if you don't give it any additional parameters. (i.e. run `cc / gcc "source"`).

You can force `gcc` to produce a `.out` on windows with `gcc "source" -o "dest.out"`.

If your compiler outputs one extension by default (in your case it seems that `.exe` is the default which is perfectly OK for Windows), I would stick with it. No need to worry about not getting the other type.

Comment: The user is writing 'I installed the visual studio 2015 on windows 10 and i compiled the code as "cc hello_world.c"', so it was Windows....

Comment: I modified the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Binary executing files in Windows have extension `exe`. I am not sure about `com`-files supporting, but it is not our case. Extension `out` usually uses for writing a text protocol when some program is working. I could guess that it is your program itself, being launched, creates `out`-file. For more help, provide at least what program environment is used to compile your C-program.

Answer (score 2):

[`a.out`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.out) temporary file that is created after compilation of a **c program** is actually an [Object Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_code) for Unix-like operating systems. Object code is used for writing system calls which implements the code functionality and relocation information for linker to help it find the object code in memory(more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123480/are-object-files-platform-independent)).

Compiler compiles the code and writes a file known as object code and in linux/unix the file is known as [a.out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.out). 
This file can be further [linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) to definitions(OR more technically [libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)#Linking)) present in the operating system to form the **executable image**.

**For example in Windows :**
[image]

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your answer can be confusing because usually `a.out` is an *executable*, not an obj file. Normally `.o` is the result of compilation, before linking (object file).